# The proof of a discrete Fourier identity in quantum field theory

Tags: momentum, fourier-transform, crystals, discrete

On page 25, in the book *Quantum Field Theory for the Gifted Amateur* by Tom Lancaster and Stephen. J Blundell, it states the following:

> We impose periodic boundary conditions forcing $e^{ikja}=e^{ik(j+N)a}$. The wave vector therefore takes the values $2\pi m/Na$, where $m$ is an integer in the range $-N/2<m\le N/2$. Note that
>   \begin{equation}
> \sum_je^{ikja}=N\delta_{k,0}.
> \end{equation}

Clearly this is true for $k=0$, but I can't see how this holds true for $k\ne 0$.

Comment: Note that this identity is purely mathematical once one has put in the "right" momenta. It is widely used in all of physics, including plain quantum theory or classical electrodynamics.

Comment: This question (v2) seems like an archetype of a math problem encountered in many areas of physics, e.g. crystals, and which the community consistently wants to _not_ migrate to Math.SE, cf. [this meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5713/2451).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can use the formula for the sum of a geometric progression for $k$ non equal to 0.

Comment: So:

For $k\ne 0$
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=1}^N(e^{ika})^j=\frac{(1-(e^{ika})^N)e^{ika}}{1-e^{ika}}=\frac{e^{ika}-e^{ik(1+N)a}}{1-e^{ika}}=0
\end{equation}
where the final equality follows from the imposed boundary conditions forcing $e^{ikja}=e^{ik(j+N)a}$ and thus $e^{ika}-e^{ik(1+N)a}=0$ where $j=1$.